# how to make colspan of table footer flexible with javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a dynamic html table where I want to place sums in the footer at certein calculated positions.
Those fields have a fixed colspan of `1`.
Other fields should be displayed as single column with variable colspan.

In my example below, I want to add those footer sums at positions, where the header contains the word "Sum" - note that those sums could occour on any position in the table.

All the header data and the "needle" fields are stored in arrays.

I'm getting the positions of the needles in the header array with `position = header.indexOf(column); //position of current needle`

Afterwards the colspan is calculated with `colSpan  = position - last_pos - el_span; //calculate colspan`

Finally, the elements are added to the footer using

```
$('#testTable tfoot tr').append("<th colspan="+colSpan+"></th>");
$('#testTable tfoot tr').append("<th colspan="+el_span+">Sum</th>");
```

Somehow, the first sum field is always on the wrong position - how to adapt my algorithm to fix that issue?

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const header    = ["Info","Info","Info","Info","Sum1","Sum2","Info","Sum3","Info","Info","Sum4"];
  const needles   = ["Sum1","Sum2","Sum3","Sum4"];
  const el_span   = 1; //fixed colspan for sum column
  let   position  = 0; //position pointer, starting from 0
  let   last_pos  = 0; //last position stored
  let   colSpan   = 0; //calculated colspan, starting with 0
  
  for(const column of needles)
  {
    position = header.indexOf(column); //position of current needle
    colSpan  = position - last_pos - el_span; //calculate colspan
    last_pos = position;
    
    $('#testTable tfoot tr').append("<th colspan="+colSpan+"></th>");
    $('#testTable tfoot tr').append("<th colspan="+el_span+">Sum</th>");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="testTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>245</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>245</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>245</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>245</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
    
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: May it is caused because an Array starts at index 0 and your el_span is set to 1.  So on the first iteration it gets decremented by 1 what then results in the wrong position

Comment: I realise my approach ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pa6Lnyeo/1/)) inserts a lot empty `<th>` elements, but I'd definitely take the simpler approach (if only as a first step).

Comment: @grisuu - thats correct, but even if i set the el_span to 0 in the first loop attempt, it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidThomas - I would use the attempt with the empty fields only as a backup if it really doesn't work with colspan's, but it's a requirement and there must be a way :)

Comment: Remember that only Firefox supports `colspan="0"`, otherwise it's equivalent to `colspan="1"`

Comment: @user2495207 a colspan of 0 is never used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it by creating a new `spans[]` array (initially containing an object `{text:'', colspan:0}`) and a *cursor*, updated on certain conditions while looping inside the `header[]` array.

Then I loop the `header[]`.

Each time a `header[]` element is **not** inside the `needles[]` array, I increment the *colspan* value of the object inside `span[]`.

If the header element is included in the `needles[]` array, I add a new object to the `spans[]` array.

At the end, I have an array with *texts* and *colspans* for each footer element to append.

It seems to work well, it also doesn't care of the *order* of elements inside the `needles[]` array.

**Run the *snippet* Full-Page**, to avoid the `console.log()` *overlapping* the table).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const header = ["Info", "Info", "Info", "Info", "Sum1", "Sum2", "Info", "Sum3", "Info", "Info", "Sum4"];
  const needles = ["Sum1", "Sum2", "Sum3", "Sum4"];

  const spans = []; // new array
  let cursor = 0; // cursor
  spans[cursor] = {
    text: '',
    colspan: 0
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
    if (!needles.includes(header[i])) { // if not included, ++colspan
      spans[cursor].colspan++;
    } else {
      if (i !== 0) cursor++; // only needed when we have a needle
                             // in the first header element

      // here I create the new objects
      // with the text Sum1, Sum2, etc
      // and colspan=1
      spans[cursor] = {};
      spans[cursor].text = header[i];
      spans[cursor].colspan = 1;

      if (i === header.length - 1) continue; // if I am at the end 
                                             // of the header array,
                                             // skip the next block


      // if the next element in the header array is not included
      // in needles, I already create a new element with
      // colspan = 0 for the next loop.
      // If the next element is also in needles it's not necessary
      // as it will be catched by else{} block in the next loop
      if (!needles.includes(header[i + 1])) {
        cursor++;
        spans[cursor] = {};
        spans[cursor].text = '';
        spans[cursor].colspan = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(spans);

  for (const span of spans) {
    $('#testTable tfoot tr').append(`<th colspan="${span.colspan}">${span.text}</th>`);
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 150px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="testTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>245</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>245</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>245</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>245</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually this is quite smart and really working - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**A Table Builder**

This solution has a tableBuilder function that creates the table from the header array and accepts optional parameters for caption and row count. Since the header columns determine the footer layout the "needles" property seems extraneous and is not used. There's no need to use jQuery, especially since the dependency has been removed from Bootstrap 5.

The snippet creates 2 tables, one from the header array and another from the reversed header array.  The sum columns may be moved around in any order and the colspans are calculated correctly. And if OP only wants the footer, and not the entire table, it would be easy to modify the builder to add only that part.

**Run the code snippet to try.**

*You may need to scroll down to view the second table*

```js
const header = ["Info", "Info", "Info", "Info", "Sum1", "Sum2", "Info", "Sum3", "Info", "Info", "Sum4"];

function tableBuilder(selector, header, caption, rowCount) {

  let thead = "",
    tbody = "",
    tfoot = "",
    row = "",
    n = 0;

  header.forEach(p => {

    thead += `<th>${p}</th>`;

    row += `<td> </td>`;

    if (p.indexOf("Sum") >= 0) {
      if (n > 0) tfoot += `<th colspan="${n}"></td>`;
      tfoot += `<th>${p}</th>`;
      n = 0;
    } else n++;

  });
  
  // add last column when not a sum
  if (n > 0) tfoot += `<th colspan="${n}"></th>`;
  
  for (n = 0; n < (rowCount || 4); n++) tbody += `<tr>${row}</tr>`;

  let table = document.querySelector(selector);

  table.innerHTML = `
  <caption>${caption || "Table"}</caption>
  <thead class="table-secondary"><tr>${thead}</tr></thead>
  <tbody>${tbody}</tbody>
  <tfoot class="table-light"><tr>${tfoot}</tr></tfoot>
  `;

}

// Test

tableBuilder("#table1", header, "Table", 2);

tableBuilder("#table2", header.reverse(), "Table - Reversed Header", 4);
```

```css
th {
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.table caption {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-2">
  <table id="table1" class="table table-striped table-bordered caption-top"></table>
  <table id="table2" class="table table-striped table-bordered caption-top"></table>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: This table builder is awesome - unfortunaly I can't use it because the table is built before using a tool called [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) - The given, filled table is considered as input, and the footer should be the output.